# What is the difference between related SQLite data-types like INT, INTEGER, SMALLINT and TINYINT?

Tags: sqlite

When creating a table in SQLite3, I get confused when confronted with all the possible datatypes which imply similar contents, so could anyone tell me the difference between the following data-types?

```
INT, INTEGER, SMALLINT, TINYINT

DEC, DECIMAL

LONGCHAR, LONGVARCHAR

DATETIME, SMALLDATETIME
```

Is there some documentation somewhere which lists the min./max. capacities of the various data-types?  For example, I guess `smallint` holds a larger maximum value than `tinyint`, but a smaller value than integer, but I have no idea of what these capacities are.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`SQLite`, technically, has no data types, there are [storage classes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) in a manifest typing system, and yeah, it's confusing if you're used to traditional `RDBMS`es. Everything, internally, is stored as text. Data types are coerced/converted into various storage locations based on affinities (ala data types assigned to columns).

The best thing that I'd recommend you do is to :

1. Temporarily forget everything you used to know about standalone database datatypes
2. Read the above link from the `SQLite` site.
3. Take the types based off of your old schema, and see what they'd map to in `SQLite`
4. Migrate all the data to the `SQLite` database.

**Note:** The datatype limitations can be cumbersome, especially if you add time durations, or dates, or things of that nature in `SQL`. `SQLite` has very few built-in functions for that sort of thing. However, `SQLite` does provide an easy way for you to make your own built-in functions for adding time durations and things of that nature, through the [`sqlite3_create_function`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) library function. You would use that facility in place of traditional stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link.  Does this mean I should stick to the basic types of text, numeric, integer, real, none?  Seems very limited to me, especially coming from a MSSQL, Foxpro and Oracle background.  Regards.

Comment: I agree with you, it does seem limited at first.  However, I think you'll find that SQLite is very forgiving in how you put data into the database via its affinity system.  SQLite isn't standalone - it's designed to be a little database backend that you place in small applications to be accessed only via a database access API in code.  Solving problems in SQLite is usually a matter of figuring out how they want you to do it.

Comment: I'd stick to the basic types.

Comment: @Alan: You might find it useful to declare numeric-affinity columns as `DATE` or `BOOLEAN`, but I wouldn't bother distinguishing between different sizes of integers.  This is especially true for the case of `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, the one case where the exact type name matters.

Comment: "Everything is stored as text" seems to be wrong according to https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html, which says numbers are stored as compact varints / float64, and only blob and text is stored as strings

Answer (score 52):

The difference is syntactic sugar.  Only a few substrings of the type names matter as for as the type affinity is concerned.

- INT, INTEGER, SMALLINT, TINYINT → INTEGER affinity, because they all contain "INT".
- LONGCHAR, LONGVARCHAR → TEXT affinity, because they contain "CHAR".
- DEC, DECIMAL, DATETIME, SMALLDATETIME → NUMERIC, because they don't contain any of the substrings that matter.

The rules for determining affinity are listed at the [SQLite site](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

If you *insist* on strict typing, you can implement it with `CHECK` constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   N   INTEGER CHECK(TYPEOF(N) = 'integer'),
   Str TEXT CHECK(TYPEOF(Str) = 'text'),
   Dt  DATETIME CHECK(JULIANDAY(Dt) IS NOT NULL)
);
```

But I never bother with it.

As for the capacity of each type:

- `INTEGER` is always signed 64-bit.  Note that SQLite optimizes the [storage](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#record_format) of small integers behind-the-scenes, so TINYINT wouldn't be useful anyway.
- `REAL` is always 64-bit (`double`).
- `TEXT` and `BLOB` have a [maximum size](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) determined by a preprocessor macro, which defaults to 1,000,000,000 bytes.

Comment: Nice trick. Do note that this approach *does require* a value-to-be-inserted/updated to have the same storage class as the one in `TYPEOF`. So, attempts to insert a TEXT that would otherwise be converted to NUMERIC/INTEGER storage class by SQlite (i.e., such conversion is lossless as per https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) would fail. In other words this approach is *stricter* than the ad-hoc approach of inserting the value and then somehow magically validating the storage class used to store that value by SQLite. For a more permissive approach, see my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Most of those are there for compatibility. You really only have integer, float, text, and blob. Dates can be stored as either a number (unix time is integer, microsoft time is float) or as text.

Comment: I've used it for web based projects where ultimately everything ended up being text put into an html page anyway. I dispensed with a lot of data conversion and just used text for most of the columns. It worked out well.

Answer (score 4):

`NULL`. The value is a NULL value.

`INTEGER`. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

`REAL`. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

`TEXT`. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

`BLOB`. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to answer from dan04, if you want to blindly insert a `NUMERIC` other than zero represented by a `TEXT` but ensure that text *is convertible* to a numeric:

```
your_numeric_col NUMERIC CHECK(abs(your_numeric_col) <> 0)
```

Typical use case is in a query from a program that treats all data as text (for uniformity & simplicity, since SQLite already does so). The nice thing about this is that it allows constructs like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (..., your_numeric_column, ...) VALUES (..., some_string, ...)
```

which is convenient in case you're using placeholders because you don't have to handle such non-zero numeric fields specially. An example using Python's `sqlite3` module would be,

```
conn_or_cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO table VALUES (" + ",".join("?" * num_values) + ")",   
    str_value_tuple)  # no need to convert some from str to int/float
```

In the above example, all values in `str_value_tuple` will be escaped and quoted as strings when passed to SQlite. However, since we're not checking explicitly the type via `TYPEOF` but only *convertibility to type*, it will still work as desired (i.e., SQLite will either store it as a numeric or fail otherwise).