# What is the difference between SQLite integer data types like int, integer, bigint, etc.?

Tags: sqlite

**What is the difference between integer data types in sqlite?**

INT
INTEGER
TINYINT
SMALLINT
MEDIUMINT
BIGINT
UNSIGNED BIG INT
INT2
INT8

Which one can store 32-bit integers and which one can store 64-bit values? Is there support for 128-bit?

I find integer data size a little confusing for now, INTEGER for example can store up to 64-bit signed integers, but values may occupy only 32 bits on disk.

Calling `sqlite3_column_int` on an INTEGER column will work only if the value stored is less that int32 max value, how will it behave if higher?

Comment: superset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761563/what-is-the-difference-between-related-sqlite-data-types-like-int-integer-smal

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From the SQLite3 documentation:

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> Most SQL database engines (every SQL database engine other than
>   SQLite, as far as we know) uses static, rigid typing. With static
>   typing, the datatype of a value is determined by its container - the
>   particular column in which the value is stored.
>
> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the
>   datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its
>   container. The dynamic type system of SQLite is backwards compatible
>   with the more common static type systems of other database engines in
>   the sense that SQL statement that work on statically typed databases
>   should work the same way in SQLite. However, the dynamic typing in
>   SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional
>   rigidly typed databases.

So in MS Sql Server (for example), an "int" == "integer" == 4 bytes/32 bits.

In contrast, a SqlLite "integer" can hold whatever you put into it: from a 1-byte char to an 8-byte long long.

The above link lists all types, and gives more details about Sqlite "affinity".

The C/C++ interface you're referring to must work with strongly typed languages.

So there are two APIs: sqlite3_column_int(), max 4-byte; and sqlite3_column_int64()

http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_int64

Comment: Note, however, that the one place the exact type name matters is in autoincrement columns: These must be `INTEGER` (and `PRIMARY KEY`), not just `INT`.