# Is there type Long in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I want to create a table with the column type `Long` instead of `Integer`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 253):

From the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storage_classes_and_datatypes)

> **INTEGER**. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

Since `long` is 8 byte and `INTEGER` can also save values of 8 bytes, you can use `INTEGER`.

Comment: i input 1549251913000 and mismatch when getting it from SQLite

Comment: Please check whether you're mistakenly type casting it to `int`, make sure you're using long throughout.

Answer (score 23):

Create the column as an `INTEGER` type:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_A + "("
                + KEY + " INTEGER" + ")");
```

Put the `long` value in `INTEGER` column:

```
contentValues.put(KEY, object.getLongValue());
db.insert(TABLE_A, null, contentValues);
```

**Important:** retrieve the value from cursor as `LONG`

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_A, null);
long value = cursor.getLong(0);
```

Comment: What's the difference compared to just using `INTEGER` all the way?

Answer (score 19):

I don't think there is type long. Either you can use INTEGER (or) Numeric. Here is link with supported data types http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 5):

His above link depicts a 64 bit Integer or Essentially a long, also see 
[What is the difference between SQLite integer data types like int, integer, bigint, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337882/sqlite-and-integer-types-int-integer-bigint)

and 
[Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android)

Answer (score 5):

You just define a column with Integer type. SQLite sets the column length to 1,2,4,8 depending on your input.

Answer (score 4):

SQLIte will set suitable integer width depend on your input

Answer (score 2):

the **INTEGER** can store the **long** but to get long from **cursor** should do like this :

```
int type = cursor.getType(j);

String value = cursor.getString(j);
try {
       int intValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
       field.set(object, intValue);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       long longValue = Long.parseLong(value);
       field.set(object, longValue);
}
```

i use this to store **timestamp** in **sqlite**