# Problems with autoincrement in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

In linux, on the command line (sqlite3), I use the following version of Sqlite:

```
SQLite version 3.7.6.3
```

In an sqlite tutorial (http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) I have read the following statement:

```
On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly 
given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer,
usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use.
```

I have the following table (.schema addresses):

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
id int primary key not null,
ipaddr text not null,
locked int,
date text not null,
quater int,
count not null);
CREATE INDEX addresses_index1 on addresses (ipaddr);
```

Now, if I am inserting the following row as mentioned above (no values for id), it does not work:

```
insert into addresses (ipaddr, locked, date, quater, count) values
('0.0.0.0', 0, '2016/12/13', 0, 1);
```

I get the error message

```
Error: addresses.id may not be NULL
```

But the tutorial said that I can do it exactly this way.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `integer primary key`, not `int primary key`. The `not null` is redundant with `integer primary key`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what is the difference between int and integer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337882/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlite-integer-data-types-like-int-integer-bigi check that link out that describes the difference between INT and INTEGER. Note the comment on that page with 21 upvotes to the comments. When it comes to autoincrementiing, your column **has to be** of datatype INTEGER even though naming INT gives you the same affinity as INTEGER.

Comment: `integer primary key` aliases with ROWID and can be autofilled. `int primary key` is a primary key with integer affinity but it does not alias with ROWID and does not get the auto-filling properties.