# Different types of variables in android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql=String.format(
                "create table %s"+"(%s int primary key, %s int, %s text, %s int, %s text)",
                TABLE, Column_ID, Column_Descreption, Column_Price, Column_Photo_URL);

        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
```

My question is: are there any additional types beside **int** and **text**?
Because I need to store boolean and double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fast start take a look on this discussion: [What is the difference between related SQLite data-types like INT, INTEGER, SMALLINT and TINYINT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761563/sqlite-data-types)

Then go to this article: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Shortly java's `double` called `real` in Sqlite terms. Other details are described in resources I have mentioned. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here [SQLite datatype](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), boolean or double value doesn't exist. For storing those types you have to use or String value or Integer value (only for emulate Boolean. 0 is false, 1 is true) or REAL value for floating point value