# SQLITE: Check Type of an INSERT with CHECK TYPEOF()

Tags: sql, sqlite, constraints, typeof

I have a problem with the SQLite CHECk Constraint.

SQLite doesn't check if a inserted value is of a specific type (for example integer).

So i want to check this by the "CHECK" Constraint using the "typeof" function.

But when I execute the following query(s), I get no error and SQLite INSERT the string without a message.

What's wrong?

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test2 (test INTEGER CHECK(TYPEOF(test) == 'INTEGER'));
sqlite> INSERT INTO test2 (test) VALUES (5); //Should work
sqlite> INSERT INTO test2 (test) VALUES ('dd'); //Should not work, but works
```

Comment: Is there an issue using a "=="?  I'm a total SQL newb, but at least on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761563/sqlite-data-types) I see they're only using one equal sign.

Comment: I tried it also with a single =...with no effect

Comment: ["Prior to version 3.3.0, CHECK constraints were parsed but not enforced."](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) Is your SQLite version >= `3.3`?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed SQLite makes no distinction between `=` or `==` (see [Operators](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)).

Comment: @LS_dev That was the problem, thanks. The installed version was 3.1, in 3.3 it works, but the INTEGER in '' must be written in small letters.

Comment: @LS_dev Why not set that as an answer?

Comment: Can you try `SELECT  TYPEOF(test2) test2` for your both lines, to see what types are deliverd ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried your Queries using NavicatLite on a SQLite3 database and it show

> 19 - constraint failed

for the text insert, So it seems to be correct.

Please try

```
select sqlite_version();
```

and check if it shows something above version 3.3 (LS_dev thank you for your comment)