# How to avoid inserting the wrong data type in SQLite tables?

Tags: debugging, error-handling, sqlite, data-consistency

SQLite has this [*"feature"*](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3) whereas even when you create a column of type `INTEGER` or `REAL`, it allows you to insert a string into it, even a string without numbers in it, like *"the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog"*.

How do you prevent this kind of insertions to happen in your projects?

I mean, when my code has an error that leads to that kind of insertions or updates, I want the program to give an error, so I can debug it, not simply insert garbage in my database silently.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can implement this using the `CHECK` constraint (see [previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2762020/596273)).  This would look like

```
   CREATE TABLE T (
       N   INTEGER CHECK(TYPEOF(N) = 'integer'),
       Str TEXT CHECK(TYPEOF(Str) = 'text'),
       Dt  DATETIME CHECK(JULIANDAY(Dt) IS NOT NULL)
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

The better and safer way is write a function (isNumeric, isString, etc) that validates the user input...