# ProgrammingError: function lower(bigint) does not exist (Django, AWS RDS, PostgreSQL)

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, case-insensitive

In my Django Rest Framework project, I have a custom filter_backends that allows filtering by case insensitively:

```py
class CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
    
        if ordering:
            new_ordering = []
            for field in ordering:
             #   field = str(field)
                print(Lower(field))
                if field.startswith('-'):
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field[1:]).desc())
                else:
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field).asc())
            return queryset.order_by(*new_ordering)
    
        return queryset
```

This works fine in development.

Now I hosted the django app on elastic beanstalk and I configured a postgresql database via amazon relational database service (RDS).

When I try now to call the API, I get this error:

> ProgrammingError at /api/profile_list/ function lower(bigint) does not
> exist LINE 1: ..."."author_id") GROUP BY "user_user"."id" ORDER BY
> LOWER(COUN...
>
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You
> might need to add explicit type casts.

This error appears only in the RDS deployment.

I tried to type cast the fields in django with:

```
field = str(field)
```

But this is not working. Is there any way to allow caseinsensitive ordering without the lower function, or how can I conditionally check if it is a number (and cast then?) or a text abd

Comment: Why do you even need case insensitive ordering for a **number**? Clearly you want to be checking what your field actually is before using the `Lower` function.

Comment: I wonder why this code is working with my local db.sqlite, but not on RDS. How should I check the type before using Lower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you use `Lower` on a field which is perhaps an `IntegerField` or something else. You want to be checking what your field is before actually using `Lower`:

```py
from django.db import models


def get_field_type(field_name, queryset):
    stripped_field_name = field_name.lstrip('-')
    if stripped_field_name in queryset.query.annotations:
        return queryset.query.annotations[stripped_field_name].output_field
    return queryset.model._meta.get_field(stripped_field_name)


class CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
    
        if ordering:
            new_ordering = []
            for field in ordering:
                if not isinstance(get_field_type(field, queryset), (models.CharField, models.TextField)):
                    # Most of the character type fields inherit from CharField.
                    # I might miss a few fields here so you would need to make sure
                    new_ordering.append(field)
                elif field.startswith('-'):
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field[1:]).desc())
                else:
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field).asc())
            return queryset.order_by(*new_ordering)
    
        return queryset
```

Comment: How can I do this for additional fields that I declare in the serializer? Where I dont have a model type.. e.g. I save "number_of_authors" in Count(authors.id)

Comment: @alexrogo I have edited the answer and added a function to get the fields type. Do check.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the additional question from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551259/programmingerror-function-lowerbigint-does-not-exist-django-aws-rds-postgr#comment117650834_66551259):

> I wonder why this code is working with my local db.sqlite, but not on RDS. ...

The PostgreSQL `lower` function (as used on RDS) [only accepts text values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL).

The SQLite `lower` function also accepts integers, [although it is not explicitly mentioned in the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#lower).

This probably has to do with the fact that ["SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system."](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) Also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2761573).

This illustrates why it can be advantageous to use the same RDBMS both locally and in production.

NOTE:

Although SQLite does not complain when you do something like

```sql
... ORDER BY LOWER("my_integer_field")
```

the result can be surprising, because it will be in [lexicographic order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45950665).

For example

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`

will be sorted as text, resulting in

`[1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`